# Почему value type по дефолту immutable (Swift)?

Tags: swift

Всем привет! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в Swift Value type по дефолту является неизменяемым? Почему конкретно для структур и энумов, мне необходимо использовать mutating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct` и `enum` для того и предназначены, чтобы представлять типы значений (value type) в отличие от ссылочных типов(reference type, `class`). Когда что использовать - [пример](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

Поскольку их поведение как типов является поведением хранения/копирования по значению (то бишь с гарантией неизменности объекта), то `mutating` используется для явного указания отличного от дефолтного поведения в случае с методами (для свойств такое указание это `let` или `var`). Подробнее например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035648/swift-and-mutating-struct#24035861)

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за разъяснение :)